# After so many calls, API(which has no usage limit) begins returning API returning <html><head>

Tags: python, html, api, response

I am using the Immune Epitope Database API(http://tools.iedb.org/main/tools-api/) with Python to retrieve binding prediction data for a list of 525 peptide sequences that I have. I have checked the IEDB documentation, and it explicitly states there is no usage limit; however, after I call the API so many times as I iterate through my list of  sequence, I begin receiving

```
< html >< head >
```

as a response object for every call instead of the usual response object such as

```
['HLA-B*57:01', '1', '1', '9', '9', 'ITFDNLKTL', 'ITFDNLKTL', 'ITFDNLKTL', '0.615', '0.38']
```

The number of calls after which this occurs is different every time I run my script, so I know it doesn't have to do anything with what I am inputting into API call.

For example, sometimes it will begin returning `< html >< head >` after 125 calls, 79 calls, 23 calls, etc.

After it returns `< html >< head >` once, all of the proceeding response objects are `< html >< head >`.

Just to be safe, I began using the time module and setting a 30 second sleep time after every 25 calls, which did nothing to stop this problem.

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Are you submitting your jobs one by one? This will likely overload their server.

Comment: There might be no usage limit, but their user guidelines explicitly state: "Please do not submit more than 1 job at a time. Instead, wait for your submitted job to complete before submitting another request. You may of course submit multiple sequences/alleles/lengths in any given request. Waiting for your submitted job to complete before submitting another will help to keep resources available for other users." See http://tools.iedb.org/main/usage-guidelines/

Comment: Yes, I have been submitting requests one by one.